# Google CloudRun redirect non-www to www

Tags: google-cloud-run

Google's CloudRun is capable of redirecting http to https without any configuration. I was not able to find any solution that would instruct CloudRun to respond 301 Permanent Redirect to all non-www requests.

I was able to instruct CloudRun to handle both www and non-www but without redirection.

I am familiar with how to set up the required logic with nginx and a traditional server. I could also do this in the application itself but since CloudRun is a serverless product, it would be better to handle this state before the app is even invoked.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

When you reach Cloud Run, you first lands on GFE (Google Front End). This layer ensure the security (if you set your Cloud Run service in no-allow-authenticated mode, perform DDoS mitigation at Google grade, expose and manage the SSL certificates, route the request to the correct services,...). So, a lot of job for this layer but you can't customize it.

If you want to add customization, you have to add a new layer, a [HTTPS Global Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https). Now you can define [serverless NEG backends](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/setting-up-serverless-negs) to reach serverless product (Cloud Run, Cloud Functions, App Engine).

It doesn't offer as much as customization as a NGINX managed by yourselves, but you can perform more things.